# how to extract the value of data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have two data attribute and i want to grab the value of the data-attribute.

```
<div class="message" data-error-message="password reset <p><b>The e-mail address you entered does not exist.</b><br></p>
<p>Check if you entered email correctly or&nbsp;<a href=www.gmail.com target="target">create a new account</a>.</p></div>

<div  data-error-message="email You can’t leave this field empty!"></div>
```

**Output should be** = password reset The e-mail address you entered does not exist , email You can’t leave this field empty.

```
var msg = jQuery('[data-error-message]').map(function() {
   return jQuery(this).data('error-message').replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").replace("&nbsp;","").trim().split('.').join(' ');
}).get();
var msg = msg.join(',')
console.log(msg)
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser for this, not regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Wait, does your data attribute contain HTML or is that a typo?

Comment: Typo: Should  '<div class="message" data-error-message="password reset` ?
be `<div class="message" data-error-message="password reset">` 
*ie missing* **`">`**

Comment: yes it contains html in my data attribute.

Comment: i was looking for making the changes to the first data attribute value and then mapping the second data attribute value  to it

Answer (score 0):

You can create an in-memory node and extract its text.

```js
var msg = jQuery('[data-error-message]').map(function() {
  var error = jQuery(this)
    .data('error-message')
    .replace(/\n|\r/g,'')
    .trim()
    .split('.')
    .join(' '),
    inmemory = $('<div/>', {
      html: error
    });
  return inmemory.text();
}).get();

var msg = msg.join(',')
console.log(msg)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message" data-error-message="password reset <p><b>The e-mail address you entered does not exist.</b><br></p>
<p>Check if you entered email correctly or&nbsp;<a href=www.gmail.com target=target>create a new account</a>.</p>"></div>

<div data-error-message="email You can’t leave this field empty!"></div>
```